# Order of GORM cascaded saves depending on field names?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, cascade

I have the following arrangement of classes:

```
class A {
    static belongsTo = [c: C]
    B b
}

class B {
    static belongsTo = [c: C]
}


class C {
    static hasMany = [bbs: B, aas: A]
}
```

If I now create instances of these classes...

```
B b = new B()
A a = new A()
a.b = b

C c = new C()
c.addToBbs(b)
c.addToAas(a)
```

... and try to save c...

```
c.save()
```

... I get an `org.hibernate.TransientObjectException Message object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: B`.

What I think GORM does is first to cascade the save to `c.aas` and then it stumbles over the instance `a.b` which is not saved yet. Therefore the exception.

Now **the trick**: If I renamed the `aas` property of `C` to `xxs`, it works:

```
class C {
    static hasMany = [bbs: B, xxs: A]
}
```

`b` gets saved first, then `a`. GORM seems to cascade the saves in lexicographic order of the fields (first `bbs`, then `xxs`)!

**How can I control the sequence GORM uses for the save cascading** (except renaming the fields, which seems very brittle to me)?

Comment: This might not answer your exact question, but were the saves wrapped in a transaction? I would expect your first attempt to work as long as everything was transactional.

Comment: Yes. There was an active transaction when saving.

Comment: Sorry, hit the edit button too early. Does it work if you use "c.addToAas(a)" (without the c.addToBbs(b))? I'm not sure if saves will cascades down to a third level but worth a shot (I'd also be interested to know if Gaurav's suggestion for "cascade: save" works, but I wouldn't expect it to make a difference, given the default mapping for hasMany is "cascade: all".)

Comment: Hello, Trying to clean up unanswered. Did you solve this? Maybe you can answer your own question.

Comment: I did not solve it. There might just not be a way to control it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, GORM doesn't provide a way to control the sequence in which save cascades are applied to properties.

I think you should be able to solve this by using one of the following approaches:

1] Explicitly save `B`'s instance before saving `A`'s (like one always does for a single association without a `belongsTo`)

```
B b = new B().save()  
A a = new A(b: b)  // b should already be persisted as A doesn't `belongsTo` B
C c = new C()
c.addToBbs(b)
c.addToAas(a)
c.save()
```

2] Define [custom cascading behavior](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/single.html#customCascadeBehaviour) for property `b` in class `A`

```
class A {
    static belongsTo = [c: C]
    B b

    static mapping = {
        b cascade: 'save'
    }
}
```

*Note: neither approach was tested*

Answer (score 0):

In my many-to-many's, I save class C before I try to do .addTo's

```
B b = new B()
A a = new A()
a.b = b

C c = new C()
c.save()
c.addToBbs(b)
c.addToAas(a)
```

And I did have to define custom cascading behavior in some circumstances.

These articles help understand problems like this.

https://spring.io/blog/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/

https://spring.io/blog/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/

https://spring.io/blog/2010/07/28/gorm-gotchas-part-3/

Comment: This is not working out for me. C cannot be stored without the A's and B's. I know the GORM Gotcha articles (you are right, they are really good).

Comment: Yes, the order of what gets saved first matters, and what gets cascaded when you save.  Instead of changing aas to xxs to make it save in the alphabetical order, the better solution is to figure out what has to be saved first, and save them in that order...It's not very user friendly is it??